# Trouble in getting Location in Android SDK

Tags: android

I am new to Android, trying to implement Location Based Service but, I am getting errors. I am getting confused now.

Here are my files:

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/activity_main"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
tools:context="com.example.om.locationdemo.MainActivity">

<Button
    android:text="Get Location"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:id="@+id/button" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello World!"
    android:id="@+id/textView"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:textSize="20sp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/button"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="37dp" />

<Button
    android:text="Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginBottom="137dp"
    android:id="@+id/button2" />
</RelativeLayout>



**AndroidManifest.xml**

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.om.locationdemo">



<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
        <uses-permission                                                                         android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
        <uses-permission                                                                         android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
        <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    </activity>

  </application>

  </manifest>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
    package com.example.om.locationdemo;

     import android.Manifest;
     import android.content.Context;
     import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
     import android.location.Location;
     import android.location.LocationListener;
     import android.location.LocationManager;
     import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
     import android.support.v4.content.LocalBroadcastManager;
     import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
     import android.os.Bundle;
     import android.test.mock.MockContentProvider;
     import android.test.mock.MockContext;
     import android.view.View;
     import android.widget.Button;
     import android.widget.TextView;
     import android.widget.Toast;

     public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
     Button b1, b2;
     TextView tv;
     LocationManager lmngr;
     LocationListener llm;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        b1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
        b2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button2);
        tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
        lmngr = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        llm = new LocationListener() {
            @Override
            public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
                tv.setText("Latitude = " + location.getLatitude() +           "             Longitude's = " + location.getLongitude());
            }

            @Override
            public void onStatusChanged(String s, int i, Bundle bundle) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderEnabled(String s) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onProviderDisabled(String s) {
                                                                                         Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Please Enable Location Service", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
          };

           b1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                lmngr.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, llm);

            }
          });

          b2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {  
 lmngr.requestLocationUpdates
(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0, 0, llm);

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: What exactly you want to do?

Comment: stack trace  , please

Comment: I am trying to get Latitude and Longtitude  but below statements are giving me an error...lmngr.requestLocationUpdates
(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,0, 0, llm);lmngr.requestLocationUpdates
(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,0, 0, llm);